# Is there any function to merge to arrow tables by key using apache arrow in C++?

Tags: c++, pandas, dataframe, apache-arrow

I have no problems reading and writting CSV files. But I would like to perform some merge operations of two tables by key, handle missing values and duplicates... in a pandas-like way. I choosed Apache Arrow because it seems to be a supported library to manage large datasets and I was looking for something similar to pandas in python to be used in C++. But I don't find those functionalities implemented... I don't know if I am missing something.

I was expecting to find Join functions but I only find them for Pyarrow. Any advice? Thank you!